# Port javadoc to ant task: How implement "[@files]" option?

Tags: ant, build-process, javadoc

I'm trying to add javadoc to my ant build process do not really have an idea how to "convert" one option of javadoc into the ant task "< javadoc >".
Here the javadoc usage:

```
usage: javadoc [options] [packagenames] [sourcefiles] [@files]
```

This is what I already tried:

```
    <javadoc sourcefiles="build/sourcefiles.txt">
    </javadoc>
```

And I want to have the option [@files] in my ant task, but could not find a proper way to do so...may you have any idea?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Does your build/sourcefiles.txt only contain file names, or also options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest (primitive) way would be to use the `arg` subelement to supply more command line arguments.

```
<javadoc>
  <arg value="@build/sourcefiles.txt" />
</javadoc>
```

But I suppose that this will not work this way, since the `javadoc` task wants at least the required attributes to be given.

To take a list of files from a file, the `filelist` resource collection together with the `loadfile` task may help:

```
<loadfile property="sourcefiles-list"
          srcFile="build/sourcefiles.txt"
          encoding="US-ASCII" />
<javadoc destdir="...">
  <sourcefiles>
    <filelist files="${sourcefiles-list}"/>
  </sourcefiles>
</javadoc>
```

---

Actually, the *packagelist* attribute might be what you want:

```
<javadoc destdir="..." sourcepath="..."
         packageList="build/sourcefiles.txt">
</javadoc>
```

Try this first (I'm not sure if it also accepts file names there).

Comment: Thank you a lot to you!!! Your second hint with the loadfile and fileList task does the job very nicely.

Answer (score 0):

Why port it when it is available?

http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javadoc.html